# How to prevent state in React to not affect variables

Tags: reactjs, state

My code looks something like this

```
componentWillMount(){
    lotGroups = // backend call to fetch lotgroups
    setState({
        lotGroups
    )};
}
```

As I am changing lotGroups later on (using setState only) I wanted to store the initial copy of the complete set of lotGroups.
What would be the best way? I tried adding that variable to state and then updating it in componentWillMount(), but it did not work. As soon as the lotGroups updated, this got updated too.

Comment: Have a copy of IotGroups in constructor. like this.lotGroups = 'something'. You can access it later using this.IotGroups

Comment: But that will be called before componentWillUpdate right? all of my fetch logic is in componentWillUpdate. lotGroups is the variable which contains the result and I want to save it somewhere after that.

Comment: keep the initial copy in a different variable???

Comment: i mean initialise in constructor and update that variable in componentWillUpdate.

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay I tried doing that but of no use. It still got updated on state change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the initial state of the component must be set *synchronously* in the constructor, i.e.:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    lotGroups = 'initial state'
  }
}
```

You can then update the state in `componentWillMount` asynchronously from the backend call, i.e.:

```
componentWillMount () {
  fetch('backend.com')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(lotGroups => {
      this.setState({
        lotGroups
      })
    })
}
```

Or if you're using `async/await`:

```
async componentWillMount () {
  const res = await fetch('backend.com')
  const lotGroups = await res.json()

  this.setState({
    lotGroups
  })
}
```

If you want to store the contents of `lotGroups` for later without causing a component refresh you can skip the state setting in the constructor and use:

```
componentWillMount () {
  fetch('backend.com')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(lotGroups => {
      this.lotGroups = lotGroups
    })
}
```

Which you can then reference later as `this.lotGroups`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing right now. My initial state would be empty. After I make the backend call in compoenentWillMount which will populate that array. I want that backend result to be stored somewhere without it getting updated when there is a state change

Comment: You can add an `initialLotGroups: null` in your state (constructor) then only update it is it is === null in ajax return function?

Comment: @Pandaiolo tried that. It is not getting updated in componentWillMount( checked that in console logs) when I use that null condition, but somehow it is getting updated with the state.

Comment: in that case you can simply set `this.lotGroups = lotGroups`.  This will store the `lotGroups` on the component object without updating the state, see the updated example

Comment: Thanks everyone for their inputs. Turns out I was accidentally modifying the original value as use of splice on copied variable which will affect the original copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use state like this in component.

```
 state = {
  lotGroups = 'default value';
}
```

or inside constructor

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
state = {
  lotGroups = 'default value';
}
}
```

Please do not update state in componentWillUpdate() it will call render after state update and hence performance issue. Unnecessary render call.

Comment: Sorry!! got confused. It is actually componentWillMount. Not compoenentwillUpdate. I edited the post to reflect the same. Let me know if you have any insights.